# Averaged harmonic oscillator

Tags: probability

I have the solution of a harmonic oscillator given as $s(t)=\sin(\omega t)$.

Now I want to calculate the probability $P(s)$ that I find my oscillator at position $s$, when I look at the oscillator at some random time.

I think this should be very simple, but I was not able to come up with an idea to solve this, and google was not helpful this time.

Comment: The motion is periodic with period $T= 2\pi/\omega$. So the random time corresponds to a uniform distribution of $t$ on $[0,T]$. Given this, you can find the distribution of $s$ via the usual formula for [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your oscillator behaves like this: $x(t) = \sin (\omega t)$. For a particular position $x$, it takes $\mathrm{d} t$ to get to $x + \mathrm{d}x$. Their relationship is
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t} = \omega \cos (\omega t) = \omega \sqrt{1 - x^2} \, .
$$
Therefore the oscillator spends time $\mathrm{d} t = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\omega\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ between $x$ and $x+\mathrm{dx}$. The probability of finding the oscillator there is proportional to the time.

To calculate the probability, you need to normalize by the total time spent there. In your case it's half the period, i.e. $\pi/\omega$.

Therefore the probability density of finding the oscillator at $x$ is
$$
p(x) = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{1-x^2}} \,.
$$

Just to check, let's look at the total probability of finding it between -1 and 1.
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{\pi} \left [ \arcsin{x} \right ]_{-1}^{1} = \pi/\pi = 1 \,. 
$$
Therefore it is properly normalized.

**$p(\pm 1) \to \infty$ issue:**
The probability density diverges at the turning points ($x = \pm 1$). However, the physically measurable probability of finding the oscillator between any $a$ and $b$ is always finite. The divergence can be understood as follows: The $x = \pm 1$ positions are infinitely more probable than any other particular points along the trajectory, as the oscillator actually stops there, whereas it just flies through the other ones.

Comment: At first sight it is strange that the probability is $+\infty$ at $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: It might be, but the only thing that does reach infinity is the probability density, not the probability itself. If you look at any finite range of positions (even including one of the edges), you'll always get a finite answer.

Comment: Just as a side note: this issue goes away in the case of quantum harmonic oscillator.

Comment: I have the same result as the user SSF. I would say that derive probability density performed correctly. --> +1

Comment: Great, thank you for the fast and detailed answer, and especially also for resolving the infinity-problem :)